# C++ 64 bit int: pass by reference or pass by value

Tags: c++, performance, pass-by-reference, 32bit-64bit, x86-64

This is an efficiency question about 64 bit ints.  Assuming I  don't need to modify the value of a "int" parameter, should I pass it by value or reference.

Assuming 32 bit machine:

1) 32 bit int: I *guess* the answer is "pass by value" as "pass  by reference" will have overhead of extra memory lookup.

2) 64 bit int: If I pass by reference, I only pass 32 bit address on the stack, but need an extra memory lookup. So which one of them is better (reference or value)?

What if the machine is 64 bit?

regards,

JP

Comment: "efficiency" :( KISS. pass it how you pass every other bloody integer.

Comment: The compiler will probably optimze it anyway.

Comment: @pst: +1 for funny comment. man I laughed very hard.

Comment: Any decent 32-bit code generator passes the value in *two* CPU registers or just plain 8 bytes on the stack frame.  Same is true for a struct for example.  You shouldn't start thinking about passing a pointer until it is more than 16 bytes.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for the clear and to the point comment for my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pass by value - definitely. If the system is 64-bit it means it copies 64-bit word extremely fast.

Answer (score 12):

Even on a 64 bit machine pass by value is better (with some very few exceptions), because it can be passed as a register value.

Comment: I'd say *especially* on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: So passing 64-bit int "by value" is more efficient that passing 64-bit int "by reference" on both 32-bit or 64-bit machines, (even more so on 64-bit machines), right?

Comment: I am curious to know the exceptions (it thats not out of scope of the discussion :)

Comment: @JP19: I'm not sure if there are such exceptions. Maybe following situation could be such an exception: the caller has so many local variables, that not all of them can be held in registers and the address of the parameter was in use recently so it is still present in a register. But such are too esoteric assumptions; probably not worth considering...

Answer (score 6):

Pass them as a `boost::call_traits<int64_t>::param_type`. This template captures the best practices for passing any type on the supported platforms. Hence, it will be different on 32 and 64 bits platforms, but you can use the same code everywhere. It even works inside other templates where you don't know the precise type yet.

Comment: +1 this is by far the best punishment for people worried about optimizing the passing of integers, that they have to type that lot out.

Comment: Maybe its true that for 64 bit data the difference is negligible. However, the spirit of the question is worthwhile imo. What if I have a 12 byte struct? 16 byte?  Hans Passant's comment, though may not be technically verified or tested, atleast gives an indication in the right direction.

Comment: Of course, its useful to know that for 64 bit one need not worry :). (Though our code will call such kinds of functions 100s of Million times and runs for hours in general. In that case, its always good to follow what are "best" practices").

Answer (score 6):

Use a little common sense,

1. if the object requires a complex copy constructor, it's probably worth passing by reference (saying that - quite a lot of boost's objects are designed to be passed-by-value rather than reference simply because internal implementation is quite trivial) There is one odd one which I haven't really worked out, `std::string`, I always pass this by reference...
2. If you intend to modify the value that is passed in, use a reference
3. Else, PASS-BY-VALUE!

Do you have a particular performance bottleneck with arguments to functions? Else, don't spend too much time worrying about which is the best way to pass...

Optimizing by worrying about how an `int` is passed in is like pi**ing in the sea...

Answer (score 5):

For argument's sake, lets ignore the trivial case of optimisers removing differences.  Let's also say you're using Microsoft's Intel 64-bit calling conventions (which do differ from the Linux ABI), then you've got 4 64-bit registers for passing such values before you have to resort to pushing them on the stack.  That's clearly better.

For a 32-bit app, by value and they'd go straight onto the stack.  By-reference may instead put a pointer in a register (again, a few such register uses are allowed before resorting to the stack).  We can this in some output from g++ -O3 -S, calling f1(99) by value and f2(101) by const reference:

```
void f1(int64_t);
void f2(const int64_t&);

int main()
{
    f1(99);
    f2(101);
}

...

    pushl   0
    pushl   $99
    call    _Z2f1x    // by value - pushed two halves to stack

    leal    -8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    movl    $101, -8(%ebp)
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    call    _Z2f2RKx   // by const& - ugly isn't it!?!
```

The called function would then have to retrieve before first usage (if any).  The called function's free to cache the values read in registers, so that's only needed once.  With the stack approach, the value can be reread at will, so the register need not be reserved for that value.  With the pointer approach, either the pointer or 64-bit value may need to be saved somewhere more predictable (e.g. pushed, or another less useful register) should that register need to be freed up momentarily for some other work, but the 64-bit int parameter be needed again later.  All up, it's hard to guess which is faster - may be CPU/register-usage/optimiser/etc dependent, and it's not worth trying.

A node to pst's advice...

"efficiency" :( KISS. pass it how you pass every other bloody integer. - pst

...though, sometimes you apply KISS to template parameters and make them all const T& even though some may fit in registers....